# error in using date picker

Tags: ios, datepicker

the application crashed when calling this function, how ever in iPhone it works fine , but in iPad the application crashes and say

note: i'm using ActionSheetDatePicker library

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (cod = 1 , address = 0x9e...)

when i debug i found selectedDate is nil in iPad , but works fine in iPhone

```
#pragma mark - Implementation
- (void)dateWasSelected:(NSDate *)selectedDate element:(id)element {
//    self.selectedDate = selectedDate;

    //may have originated from textField or barButtonItem, use an IBOutlet instead of element

    //DATE TEXT FIELD HERE


    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];
    //Optionally for time zone converstions
    [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"..."]];
    NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:selectedDate];
    self.textFieldBirthDate.text = stringFromDate ;
    birthDate = stringFromDate ;

    //"YYYY-MM-DD"  the birthdate format

}
```

Comment: Generally by default ActionSheet uses UIPopover and hence you are facing difficulty, so request you to post some more code so that it would be easy for debugging. 
Also you can avoid this crash by checking if selected date is nil , if nil then return current date

Comment: i'm using this library https://github.com/TimCinel/ActionSheetPicker and the code crashes on the line of the function he didn't enter the function , its just get this green line on the function header and stop ,, its the same code of iPhone , i just copy the storyboard from iPhone to iPad and resize it , the same code i don't know what happen

Answer (score 2):

The git hub code which you provided is working fine for me  and I did debug the code.

When user Taps on done button (After selecting the date) below code will be executed.

```
- (void)notifyTarget:(id)target didSucceedWithAction:(SEL)action origin:(id)origin {

    if ([target respondsToSelector:action])

        objc_msgSend(target, action, self.selectedDate, origin);

    else

        NSAssert(NO, @"Invalid target/action ( %s / %s ) combination used for ActionSheetPicker", object_getClassName(target), (char *)action);

}
```

Now here make sure you are getting value for self.selectedDate , if you are not getting then please do check that you are getting a breakpoint to below code when you just select a date by scrolling.

```
- (void)eventForDatePicker:(id)sender {

    if (!sender || ![sender isKindOfClass:[UIDatePicker class]])

        return;

    UIDatePicker *datePicker = (UIDatePicker *)sender;

    self.selectedDate = datePicker.date;

}
```

These codes are present in file

> ActionSheetDatePicker.m

If you are getting the breakpoint here then make sure you are saving the date .Once you do check this the problem will be resolved.

Regards,
Anil

Comment: Once successful , please accept the answer or else let me know.